# jq - select an attribute beginning with a string

Tags: json, jq

input json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "89",
    "hostname": "abcd"
  },
  {
    "id": "89",
    "hostname": "babcd"
  }
]
```

How to modify below filter to get on output only hostname beginning with "abcd"?

```
$ jq -r '.[]|select(.hostname | contains("abcd"))' jjjj
{
  "id": "89",
  "hostname": "abcd"
}
{
  "id": "89",
  "hostname": "babcd"
}
$ jq -r '.[]|select(.hostname | contains("^abcd"))' jjjj
$
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Solution:

```
jq -r '.[]|select(.hostname | startswith("abcd"))' jjjj
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can also use `endswith()` if that's what you want to check

Comment: And if you need the output to be an array, then you should use `map`. Example: 
`jq 'map( select(.hostname | startswith("abcd") ) )'`. Then you can select the first match by simply using `| first`

Comment: And since we're on the topic -- you can also use `contains("xyz")`, if that's your cup of tee. :D