# jq - select an attribute based on a key that starts with or contains a string

Tags: jq

input.json

```json
{
  "Stack": {
    "KeypairNameB651C0C1": "key-0123456abcdefg",
    "AsgNameA7D05B90": "my-asg-name"
  }
}
```

The key names could vary, but will always begin with a set string

Similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443290/jq-select-an-attribute-beginning-with-a-string) but want to somehow get the value based on a `select(startswith("AsgName"))` for the *key*

Is this possible with jq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` / `with_entries` to access the keys ex.

```
$ jq '.Stack | with_entries(select(.key | startswith("AsgName")))' file.json 
{
  "AsgNameA7D05B90": "my-asg-name"
}
```

or

```
$ jq '.Stack | to_entries[] | select(.key | startswith("AsgName")) | .value' input.json 
"my-asg-name"
```